# NInject - Intercept everytime a property setter is called?

Tags: c#, ninject

I'm trying to detect whenever a property setter is called (and run some code as a result). I could write a method into the setter of every property:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; } set { OnChange(this); name = value; }
}
```

But this gets tedious when you have hundreds of properties. Is NInject capable of intercepting setter methods?

In terms of purpose, I'm trying to track every object which changes.

Comment: Can this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593289/ninject-strange-intercept-to-inner-set-properties

Comment: That works! Though I've just realised I'd need to create all my trackable objects with NInject so that they're within the kernel - is that likely to severely hamper performance if there's say, 5000 of them?

Comment: Ninject is a DI Container. DI Containers are meant to build up object graphs consisting of application Components (the classes that contain the application's behavior). The `Name` property however seems to be part of an object that consists of runtime data (such as a DTO or Domain entity). Your DI Container should now _nothing_ about them. If you need to use interception on runtime data, don't abuse your DI Container. Use your interception library directly.